# Entity framework create POCO class for join table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to create the POCO entity within my `datacontext` for the join table (the one created for the m2m relationship).

The reason I'm doing that is that I want to handle keys inserting in the table by my own. (Don't ask me why, several performance issues.)

So the algorithm is like that:

1. I generate the POCO class using native ADO.NET tools based on the existing table, let's say `TableAnotherTable` (this table joins two others `Table` and `AnotherTable`). Or just creating it manually.
2. I'm trying to add the migration for it. Either with `-IgnoreChanges` or not. Without `-IgnoreChanges` it tries to rename the existing table `TableAnotherTable` to `TableAnotherTable1`. Which sounds fair enough but why? It should just map the existing table to newly created POCO class.
3. I'm cleaning the `Up()` and `Down()` methods.
4. Trying to run the app and do some `CUD` operations within the context and constantly getting an error: Invalid object name `dbo.TableAnotherTable1`.

So the main question: **How can I map the join table created by entity framework to my own class in order to work with it like with regular entity?**

**Update**:

```
public class Client
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class Group
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Client> Clients {get;set;}
}
```

There is no additional configurations or something.

the name of join table in database is `GroupClient`

The poco class I'm retrieving with ADO.NET poco generation tools is:

```
[Table("GroupClient")]
public partial class GroupClient
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Group_Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Client_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to map the existing table w/o the need of migration. Are you using Code First or edmx?

Comment: @IvanStoev he already have a database _I generate the POCO class using native ADO.NET tools based on the existing table_

Comment: @IvanStoev Code first btw

Comment: Ok, can you show the initial mapping with auto join table - two entity classes and configuration (needed mainly the see that exact names, in order to create the exact equivalent 2 `one-to-many` with explicit join table).

Comment: @IvanStoev see Update in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

The initial model with auto link table should have generated `GroupClient` table with two columns `Group_Id` and `Client_Id` forming the PK.

You should be able to map it to a model with the generated explicit `GroupClient` entity shown, which already defined the properties and the PK, but you need to change the type of the existing entity navigation properties and also specify the FK's:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Client_Id")]
    public ICollection<GroupClient> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Group_Id")]
    public ICollection<GroupClient> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

I personally find using Fluent configuration much easier to follow:

*Model:*

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GroupClient> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GroupClient> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class GroupClient
{
    public int Group_Id { get; set; }
    public int Client_Id { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupClient>()
    .ToTable("GroupClient")
    .HasKey(e => new { e.Group_Id, e.Client_Id });

modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Clients)
    .WithRequired() // or (e => e.Group) in case you add nav property
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.Group_Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Groups)
    .WithRequired() // or (e => e.Client) in case you add nav property
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.Client_Id);
```

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong but it will break the existing relationships  between entities. So previously I had `Group.Clients`  and now I'll have the `Group.GroupClients` instead. The only think I want to achieve is to get mapping for the existing join table and make changes to it.

Comment: If by break you mean the existing code that is using the relationships, then yes. But there is no other way. You either represent it one or another way (you can't have them both inside the model). Both setups are equivalent from the db standpoint, but in entity model they look differently. With explicit entity you no more have the indirection provided by the auto link.

Comment: In that case thanks a lot for the perfect answers. Just to let you know the context: I'm trying to perform fast update. I need to assign the group for the 50k+ entities of clients. And I'm trying to fin out the efficient way of bulk-inserting the tons of relationships between Group And Client. Because regular one is to slow for me. And BulkInsert from the extensions can't support Complex types (ouch sqlBulkCopy).

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting something like that. By extensions you mean [this one](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)? Anyway, theoretically you could have two derived dbcontexts with different mapping to the same database, or use plain ADO bulk insert for the time critical operation.

Comment: yeap.. exactly that one extension. So much doesn't want to write stored procedures, plain sqls etc. :(

Comment: Then how about special context just for insert? Something like `public class SpecialDbContext : DbContext
 {
  public SpecialDbContext() { Database.SetInitializer<SpecialDbContext>(null); }
  public DbSet<GroupClient> GroupClient { get; set; }
 }` And keep the original as it is.